# I.E - keypress happen all the time - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem with ie, like always.

check this demo with IE9 or 8: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C5Jzw/4/)

go inside the input and hit the **enter**, i dont know why the alert will apear.

bug ?

```
    // the button
    $("#client").live("click", function(){
       alert('test'); 
    });

   // the input text
   $("#pesq_model").live("keypress", function(e){
       // testing with nothing 
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE treats `button` tags in a special way. You could use an input instead of a button:

```
<input type="button" style="border: solid #dedede 2px; width:130px;" id="client" value="Trocar Cliente" />
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VZH9T/).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$('#form_id').live("submit", {...})` instead, I think.

http://jsfiddle.net/C5Jzw/4/

```
$("#form_id").live("submit", function() {
    alert('teste');
});
```